# Error in output while solving non-linear equations

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

While running the following code I am getting this error. I need to show min value out of all solutions for the particular variable. May I please get this error fixed or get some advice how it can be done.

Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements.

Error in SpeciationCal (line 38)
m(i)=min(S.a)

```
syms a b c
    x3=[ 0.038813753 0.109515494 0.258253623 0.250365943 0.266695352 0.254064153 0.355464596 0.367390937 0.367899743];
    x1=[ 0.75197909 0.647030256 0.315659359 0.381316826 0.324185571 0.385450182 0.198472313 0.161364552 0.181784492];
    x2=[ 0.209207157 0.243454249 0.426087018 0.368317231 0.409119077 0.360485665 0.446063091 0.47124451 0.450315765];
    T=[384.2 392.1 396.4 392 406.1 405 409.6 416.2 416.4 417.1];
    
       roundn = @(x,n) round(x.*10.^n)./10.^n;
    x1=roundn(x1,5)
    x2=roundn(x2,5)
    x3=roundn(x3,5)
    
    
    N=length(x1);
    K1=zeros(N,1);K2=zeros(N,1);K3=zeros(N,1);m=zeros(N,1);n=zeros(N,1);o=zeros(N,1);
    
    for i=1:N
    K1(i)=exp((-936.28)+((40216.27)/T(i))+(151.983*(log(T(i))))+(-0.1675*(T(i))))
    K2(i)=exp((1044.78)+(-45171.42/T(i))+(-165.20*log(T(i))+(0.1511*(T(i)))))
    K3(i)=exp((-228.838)+(12587.48/T(i))+(40.68593*log(T(i)))+(-0.09838*(T(i))))
    eqns=[((a*(a-b-3*b))/((x1(i)-a-c+3*b)^4*(x2(i)-a-c)))==K1,((b*3*b)/(a-b-3*b)*(x3(i)-b))==K2,((c*c)/((x1(i)-a-c+3*b)*(x2(i)-a-c)))==K3]
    
    S=vpasolve(eqns,[a,b,c])
    warning('off', 'symbolic:numeric:NumericalInstability')
    S.a(S.a<0)=[];
    S.b(S.b<0)=[];
    S.c(S.c<0)=[];
    idxa= abs(imag(S.a)) < eps;
    idxb = abs(imag(S.b)) < eps;
    idxc = abs(imag(S.c)) < eps;
    S.a = S.a(idxa);
    S.b = S.b(idxb);
    S.c = S.c(idxc);
    m(i)=min(S.a)
    n(i)=min(S.b)
    o(i)=min(S.c)
    
    
    
    end
```

Comment: Matlab tell you that `min(S.a)` output more than one element (or is empty), but `m(i)` is supposed to store only one element. So matlab throw an error.

Comment: @obchardon I got to see that this error is occurring while running code in loop. Otherwise for single input it is giving minimum positive real value as output. Any advice for editing code to run it smoothly?

Comment: I simply guess that matlab do not find any solution for your equation and return an empty array. Are you sure that those equations have at least one solution ?

Comment: Thank you for your time, actually I got to get some mistake in loop statement.